# La propiedad 'json' no existe en el tipo 'Object'

Tags: ionic

Tengo el siguiente problema

> [ts] La propiedad 'json' no existe en el tipo 'Object'. any

Este es el código:

```
postData(credentials,type){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
    subscribe(res =>{
      resolve(res.json());
    }, (err) =>{
      reject(err);
    });
  });
 }
```

Comment: antes del suscribe pon .map(res => res.json()).    ...  y quita el .json() de tu implementación

Answer (score 3):

Si esta usando la dependencia `HttpClient` no es necesario convertir a JSON, pues la respuesta del observable ya es un JSON.

[Documentación oficial HttpClient Angular](https://angular.io/guide/http)

por esta razón el código debería quedar así:

```
  public postData(credentials: Object, type: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(apiUrl + type, credentials).subscribe(
        response => {
          resolve(response);
        },
        exception => {
          reject(exception);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```